# Cannot pair Garmin watch with Oppo A78

Tags: bluetooth-pairing, oppo

When I try to pair my Garmin watch with my Oppo A78 mobile and I start typing the passcode, it says incorrect passcode or pin. It doesn't give me enough time to enter the pin

Comment: May be there are other Bluetooth devices around you that automatically try to pair with your watch? Try to pair it in a different environment.

Comment: Thank you, I tried, but the error still occurs.